# Class Methods not linking to Tkinter GUI

Tags: class, tkinter, program-entry-point

it seems my Tkinter GUI is fine however when loaded the buttons which should activate the class methods do nadda.
I was originally trying to initiate a class instance within the main:
if_*name*_== "**main**":
     ed.EditorUI()
Where 'self' is used below 'ed' was in its place.. it said ed was undefined which prompted me to try this way. 
As you can probably tell its been a few years since I've coded.
Your help is much appreciated!

```
    import CU_picture
    import filters
    import Tkinter

    root = Tk()
    root.title('Photo Editor Version 1.10')
    #root.iconbitmap(bitmap = '12.ico')

    #img = PhotoImage(file='12.ico')
    #root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)

    #Adding File Menu
    menubar = Tkinter.Menu(root)

    filemenu = Tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    #Display above menus
    root.config(menu=menubar)

    class EditorUI(object):

        def __init__(self):

            self.name = "EditorUI"
            self.pic = 0
            self.pix = CU_picture.Picture()
            self.filters = "No Current Filters Applied"
            self.special = "cake"

        def get_specific_color(color):

            if color == "red":
                return CU_picture.Color(255, 0, 0)
            elif color == "aqua":
                return CU_picture.Color(0, 255, 255)
            elif color == "fuschia":
                return CU_picture.Color(255, 0, 255)
            elif color == "lime":
                return CU_picture.Color(0, 255, 0)
            elif color == "yellow":
                return CU_picture.Color(255, 255, 0)

        def load():

            self.pix = get_picture()
            self.pix.show()
            self.pic = 1
            error.set("Pic Loaded: "+self.filters)
            outtext.set("New Picture - Not Saved.")
            self.filters = "No Current Filters Applied"
            self.special = "cake"
            para.set("")

        def save():

            if self.pic == 0:
                error.set("No Pic Loaded")

            else:

                name = intext.get() + ".jpg"
                self.pix.write_to(name)
                outtext.set("Saved To Given Filename.")
                para.set("")

        def negative():

            if self.pic == 0:
                error.set("No Pic Loaded")

            else:
                n = filters.NegativeFilter()
                n.apply(ed.pix)
                self.pix.show()
                para.set("")

                if self.filters == "No Current Filters Applied":
                    self.filters = "Negative-F"
                    error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)
                else:
                    self.filters = self.filters + ", Negative-F"
                    error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)

        def grayscale():

            if self.pic == 0:
                error.set("No Pic Loaded")

            else:
                g = filters.GrayScaleFilter()
                g.apply(self.pix)
                self.pix.show()
                para.set("")

                if self.filters == "No Current Filters Applied":
                    self.filters = "Grayscale-F"
                    error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)
                else:
                    self.filters = self.filters + ", Grayscale-F"
                    error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)

        def posterize():

            if self.pic == 0:
                error.set("No Pic Loaded")

            else:
                p = filters.PosterizeFilter()
                p.apply(self.pix)
                self.pix.show()
                para.set("")

                if self.filters == "No Current Filters Applied":
                    self.filters = "Posterize-F"
                    error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)
                else:
                    self.filters = self.filters + ", Posterize-F"
                    error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)

        def highlight():

            if self.pic == 0:
                error.set("No Pic Loaded")

            else:

                if intext.get() == "":
                    para.set("Input Highlight distance/Colour and try again(one at a time).")

                elif self.special == "cake" and intext.get() != "":
                    self.special = intext.get()
                    outtext.set("Highlight distance: " + self.special)
                    para.set("Input Highlight colour(red, blue, aqua, fuschia, lime, yellow) for the final step.")

                elif self.special != "cake" and intext.get() != "":
                    color = get_specific_color(intext.get())
                    h = filters.HighlightFilter()
                    h.set_distance(float(self.special))
                    h.set_color(color)
                    outtext.set("Highlight colour: " + intext.get()) 
                    h.apply(self.pix)
                    self.pix.show()

                    if self.filters == "No Current Filters Applied":
                        self.filters = "Highlight-F"
                        error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)
                    else:
                        self.filters = self.filters + ", Highlight-F"
                        error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)

        def edge():

            if self.pic == 0:
                error.set("No Pic Loaded")

            else:

               para.set("Threshold?")
                if intext.get() == "":
                    para.set("Input Threshold value and try again.")

                else:
                    para.set("Threshold: " + intext.get())
                    e = filters.EdgeFilter()
                    e.set_threshold(float(intext.get()))
                    e.apply(self.pix)
                    self.pix.show()

                    if self.filters == "No Current Filters Applied":
                        self.filters = "Edge-F"
                        error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)
                    else:
                        self.filters = self.filters + ", Edge-F"
                        error.set("Pic Loaded + Current Filters: "+self.filters)

        def get_picture():
            """
            Interactively select a picture file and return it.
            """

            # Pop up a dialogue box to select a file
            file = CU_picture.pick_a_file()

            # Open the file containing the picture and load it
            pict = CU_picture.load_picture(file)

            return pict

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            EditorUI()

    intext = Tkinter.StringVar()
    outtext = Tkinter.StringVar()
    error = Tkinter.StringVar()
    para = Tkinter.StringVar()

    inp = Tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=intext)
    out = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=outtext)
    ER = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=error)
    P = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=para)

    load =      Tkinter.Button(root, text="Load", height=2, width=20, command=load)
    save =      Tkinter.Button(root, text="Save", height=2, width=20, command=save)
    negative =  Tkinter.Button(root, text="Negative-F", height=1, width=20, command=negative)
    grayscale = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Grayscale-F", height=1, width=20, command=grayscale)
    posterize = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Posterize-F", height=1, width=20, command=posterize)
    highlight = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Highlight-F", height=1, width=20, command=highlight)
    edge =      Tkinter.Button(root, text="Edge-F", height=1, width=20, command=edge)

    inp.grid(row=1, column=7)
    ER.grid(row=0, column= 0, columnspan=5, rowspan=2)
    out.grid(row=1, column= 0, columnspan=5, rowspan=2)
    P.grid(row=2, column= 0, columnspan=5, rowspan=2)

    load.grid(row=0, column=6)
    save.grid(row=0, column=7)
    negative.grid(row=1, column=6)
    grayscale.grid(row=3, column=7)
    posterize.grid(row=3, column=6)
    highlight.grid(row=2, column=6)
    edge.grid(row=2, column=7)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The argument `self` is missing in all the EditorUI methods, and `if __name__ == '__main__': EditorUI()` should be outside of the definition of the class. Apart from that, it is difficult to figure out what the problem is without knowing if the modules `CU_picture` and `filters` are relevant or not.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main problems that I see (other than what @A.Rodas mentioned above) that would prevent the buttons from doing anything is that your button commands are not actually targeting the class methods.  They're looking for root-level callables named "load", "save", etc.  Because these don't exist, you should be getting errors, and yet you say the interface works fine aside from the buttons not cooperating, which doesn't make sense to me.

To call the class methods, you must create an instance of the class.  First fix the `self` issue mentioned by @A.Rodas above, then replace the `__main__` check with this:

```
editor = EditorUI()
```

Then modify the button commands to call the methods on the editor instance:

```
load =      Tkinter.Button(root, text="Load", height=2, width=20, command=editor.load)
save =      Tkinter.Button(root, text="Save", height=2, width=20, command=editor.save)
negative =  Tkinter.Button(root, text="Negative-F", height=1, width=20, command=editor.negative)
grayscale = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Grayscale-F", height=1, width=20, command=editor.grayscale)
posterize = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Posterize-F", height=1, width=20, command=editor.posterize)
highlight = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Highlight-F", height=1, width=20, command=editor.highlight)
edge =      Tkinter.Button(root, text="Edge-F", height=1, width=20, command=editor.edge)
```

You may also consider moving all the interface creation stuff *inside* the EditorUI class, unless you have some other reason for keeping it separate.